# ggplot modifying

Tags: r

I need some help modifying this plot

[image: Normal distribution].

I want the legend to show only one of each color in this order from the top:green, blue, orange and red. The percentages on the side is in the correct positions. I also want the x-axis to show the value where it changes color in the plot (the three values that are already there is correct)

here is the code:

```
# Installer og last inn n??dvendige pakker
install.packages("tidyquant")
install.packages("GauPro")
install.packages("kernlab")
library(tidyquant)
library(GauPro)
library(kernlab)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Norwegian_Norway.1252")


# Hent historiske aksjedata for Equinor og finner ut av avkastning 1 og 3mnd etter prisen stiger over 50SMA
eqnr <- tq_get("EQNR.OL", from = "2018-01-01", to = "2022-01-01") %>%
  tq_mutate(select = close,
            mutate_fun = SMA,
            n = 50, col_rename = "sma") %>% 
  mutate(cross = if_else(close > sma, 1, 0), 
         first_cross = cross - lag(cross),
         price_1m = lead(close, 20), 
         price_3m = lead(close, 60)) %>% 
  filter(first_cross == 1) %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("price"), ~ round((.x / close - 1) *100, 2), .names = "{.col}_change"))

# Hent historiske aksjedata for Aker BP og finner ut av avkastning 1 og 3mnd etter prisen stiger over 50SMA
akrbp <- tq_get("AKRBP.OL", from = "2018-01-01", to = "2022-01-01") %>%
  tq_mutate(select = close,
            mutate_fun = SMA,
            n = 50, col_rename = "sma") %>% 
  mutate(cross = if_else(close > sma, 1, 0), 
         first_cross = cross - lag(cross),
         price_1m = lead(close, 20), 
         price_3m = lead(close, 60)) %>% 
  filter(first_cross == 1) %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("price"), ~ round((.x / close - 1) *100, 2), .names = "{.col}_change"))

# Kombinerer alle data for olje og energi aksjer til en data frame
Olje_Energi <- bind_rows(eqnr, akrbp)

# Definer omr??det for x-aksen basert p?? standardavvik og gjennomsnitt
GJ_snitt <- mean(Olje_Energi$price_1m_change, na.rm = TRUE)
Standardavvik <- sd(Olje_Energi$price_1m_change, na.rm = TRUE)
x_verdier <- seq(-3*Standardavvik + GJ_snitt, 3*Standardavvik + GJ_snitt, length.out = 50)

# Beregne sannsynlighetenstettheten for disse avkastningene
normalfordeling <- dnorm(x_verdier, mean = GJ_snitt, sd = Standardavvik)

# Rund av tallene til to desimaler
x_verdier_avrundet <- round(x_verdier, 2)

df <- data.frame(x_verdier_avrundet, normalfordeling)

# Lag en ny kolonne i data frame som angir hvilket standardavvik hver avrundet x-verdi tilh??rer
df$Sigma <- cut(df$x_verdier_avrundet, breaks = seq(-3 * Standardavvik + GJ_snitt, 3 * Standardavvik + GJ_snitt, by = Standardavvik),
                labels = c("-3??", "-2??", "-??", "??", "2??", "3??"))
df$Sigma <- factor(df$Sigma, levels = c("??", "2??", "3??", "-??", "-2??", "-3??"))

Sannsynlighet_68_26 <-df[df$Sigma %in% c("-??", "??"), "x_verdier_avrundet"]
Sannsynlighet_27_2 <- df[df$Sigma %in% c("-2??", "2??"), "x_verdier_avrundet"]
Sannsynlighet_4_26 <- df[df$Sigma %in% c("-3??", "3??"), "x_verdier_avrundet"]
Sannsynlgihet0_28 <- df[is.na(df$Sigma), "x_verdier_avrundet"]

labels <- c("-?? til +??", "-2?? til +2??", "-3?? til +3??")



# Lag et barplot med forskjellige farger for hver standardavvik
ggplot(df, aes(x = x_verdier_avrundet, y = normalfordeling, fill = Sigma)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", col = "black") +
  labs(title = "Fordeling av avkastning basert på standardavvik", x = "Avkastning", y = "Sannsynlighetstetthet") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Sannsynlighet",
                    labels = c("68.26%", "27.2%", "4.26%", "0.28%"),
                    values = c("-3??" = "orange", "-2??" = "blue", "-??" = "green", "??" = "green", "2??" = "blue", "3??" = "orange"),
                    na.value = "red")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(mean(df$x_verdier_avrundet), max(df$x_verdier_avrundet),  by = 10))+
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "right", plot.background = element_rect(size = 3, color = "black", fill = "white"))+
  annotate("text", x = GJ_snitt, y = max(df$normalfordeling), label = paste("Gjennomsnitt:", round(GJ_snitt, 2), "%"), vjust = 0.5, hjust = -.3) +
  annotate("text", x = GJ_snitt, y = max(df$normalfordeling), label = paste("Standardavvik:", round(Standardavvik, 2), "%"), vjust = 2, hjust = -.3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want only 4 colors, so you need a factor with 4 levels only, instaed of 8 levels. Here is a little replacement to transform `df` object before ggplot this: old code is commented, new one is inserted:

```
# Lag en ny kolonne i data frame som angir hvilket standardavvik hver avrundet x-verdi tilh??rer
#
# df$Sigma <- factor(df$Sigma, levels = c("??", "2??", "3??", "-??", "-2??", "-3??"))
# 
# Sannsynlighet_68_26 <-df[df$Sigma %in% c("-??", "??"), "x_verdier_avrundet"]
# Sannsynlighet_27_2 <- df[df$Sigma %in% c("-2??", "2??"), "x_verdier_avrundet"]
# Sannsynlighet_4_26 <- df[df$Sigma %in% c("-3??", "3??"), "x_verdier_avrundet"]
# Sannsynlgihet0_28 <- df[is.na(df$Sigma), "x_verdier_avrundet"]
# 
# labels <- c("-?? til +??", "-2?? til +2??", "-3?? til +3??")
# Lag et barplot med forskjellige farger for hver standardavvik

df %>% 
    mutate(
        Sigma = cut(df$x_verdier_avrundet, 
            breaks = seq(-3 * Standardavvik + GJ_snitt, 
                         3 * Standardavvik + GJ_snitt, 
                         by = Standardavvik),
            labels = c("-3", "-2", "-1", "1", "2", "3")), 
        Sigma = case_when(is.na(Sigma) ~ "4", TRUE ~ Sigma),
        Sigma = fct_collapse(
            Sigma, 
            "±σ" = c("1", "-1"),
            "±2σ" = c("2", "-2"),
            "±3σ" = c("3", "-3"),
            "±4+σ" = "4"
        )) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = x_verdier_avrundet, y = normalfordeling, fill = Sigma)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", col = "black") +
    labs(
        title = "Fordeling av avkastning basert på standardavvik", 
        x = "Avkastning", 
        y = "Sannsynlighetstetthet") +
    scale_fill_manual(
        name = "Sannsynlighet",
        values = c("green", "blue", "orange", "red")) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(
                                    mean(df$x_verdier_avrundet), 
                                    max(df$x_verdier_avrundet),  
                                    by = 10))+
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
        legend.position = "right", 
        plot.background = element_rect(linewidth = 3, color = "black", fill = "white"))+
    annotate("text", 
             x = GJ_snitt, 
             y = max(df$normalfordeling), 
             label = paste("Gjennomsnitt:", round(GJ_snitt, 2), "%"), 
             vjust = 0.5, 
             hjust = -.3) +
    annotate("text", 
             x = GJ_snitt, 
             y = max(df$normalfordeling), 
             label = paste("Standardavvik:", round(Standardavvik, 2), "%"), 
             vjust = 2, 
             hjust = -.3)
```

(keep in mind, you can transform a column step by step within single `mutate` command)

In addition, you don't need to attach packages `dplyr` and `ggplot2` manually, because they are included in tidyverse and are attached after `library(tidyverse)` already. And better not to include install.package commands into your code, this is not a part of reproducability.